# How to show the modification date of a file in Jekyll?

Tags: date, jekyll, liquid

I know that I can specify a variable `date` in the YAML frontmatter of a file and access its value with `{{ page.date }}`. This is cumbersome since one easily forgets to change the date when a file is updated. So how can I access a file's modification date?

Answer (score 37):

This is a relatively new plugin that does what you're looking for:

https://github.com/gjtorikian/jekyll-last-modified-at

(found it while searching Google for alternatives to the other answers in this thread)

Comment: Let's upvote this answer and star that project until GitHub adds that plugin to the whitelist.

Comment: I had problems installing jekyll-last-modified-at. I tried gem update, gem install, bundle exec, bundle install and tried to include the gem in my config.yml but I couldn't solve this "Dependency Error: Yikes! It looks like you don't have jekyll-last-modified-at...." I use Github, so if this is not whitelisted then it isn't good for me anyway ;-)

Answer (score 17):

From Jekyll 1.x there is a `page.path` that gives you the filename of the post or page being currently processed. Add the following filter (place e.g. in `_plugins/myfilters.rb`) to get the modification time of a given filename:

```
module Jekyll
  module MyFilters
    def file_date(input)
      File.mtime(input)
    end
  end
end

Liquid::Template.register_filter(Jekyll::MyFilters)
```

So now you can render the date on your posts and pages, e.g., as

```
{{ page.path | file_date | date_to_string }}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work for me because `page.path` is empty. I found [a post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13243469/how-can-a-jekyll-page-access-its-filename) that shows how to access it but this seems to work for posts only and not for other pages.

Comment: Hmm.. that's strange, I am using this precisely on pages, and it seems to be working fine. In case it matters, I'm using jekyll (1.1.2) and ruby (2.0.0p247).

Comment: Without the script that sets `page.path` I get `Liquid error: can't convert nil into String`. Using it I get `'generate': undefined method 'name'`. I am using ruby 1.9.3 and Jekyll 0.11.2 and it's not so easy to update ...

Comment: Well, yeah, it's going to be difficult unless you upgrade to some Jekyll 1.x. Sorry.

Comment: Just to add: If, like me, you move your site's source into a subdirectory, you need to prepend that directory to the path that comes from `page.path` (it's only source-relative), like so: `{{ page.path | prepend: "/" | prepend: site.source | file_date | date_to_string }}`

Comment: I had problems installing jekyll-last-modified-at. I tried gem update, gem install, bundle exec, bundle install and tried to include the gem in my config.yml but I couldn't solve this "Dependency Error: Yikes! It looks like you don't have jekyll-last-modified-at...." Adding a filter it was much easier and it works fine, thank you Juan

Comment: Won't work on GitHub pages because they disable custom plugins for security reasons.

Comment: Thanks for this plugin! I'm using it in a sitemap as `<lastmod>{{ page.path | file_date | date_to_xmlschema }}</lastmod>`

Answer (score 8):

Based on krlmlr's post, I wrote a pre-commit script to update modification time of the `date:` field in YAML front matter of the modified files.

```
#!/bin/sh
# Contents of .git/hooks/pre-commit

git diff --cached --name-status | grep "^M" | while read a b; do
  cat $b | sed "/---.*/,/---.*/s/^date:.*$/date: $(date -u "+%Y-%m-%d %T %Z")/" > tmp
  mv tmp $b
  git add $b
done
```

It is working fine for me. I actually use `update:` field to indicate the modified time, and `date:` field to indicate the creation time.

Comment: wfm using gh-pages! Had to add {% unless page.nodate %} {{ page.date | date: "%b %-d, %Y" }}{% endunless %} to my docpage.html in _layouts and add date: to the front matter of each file. What a nice Christmas present it was to find this.

Comment: Works like a charm! Only thing I changed was the date format. I am using `date "+%Y-%m-%d %T %z"` which matches the (current) default Jekyll date format.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think it's possible to do this without using the YAML frontmatter. Note, however, that specifying `date` in the frontmatter actually overrides the `date` given in the post's filename.

So if you have a file `2013-02-19-my-post.md` and in its frontmatter you have `date: 2013-02-20`, the frontmatter takes precedence, and the post's date is `2013-02-20`.

If you want to keep track of when a post is modified, I'm afraid there's no way to do this without using a custom field in your frontmatter. Call it `modified-date` or something. Yes, it is a bit tedious. I have a TextExpander snippet that automatically outputs current date/time in the proper format, which is handy.

Comment: Is it not possible for posts or in general? For posts I don't see the need to get their modification date, since the date encoded in the file name is fine (I rarely change posts). However, for all other Markdown files Jekyll is processing, I don't have that date and encode it in the YAML frontmatter. Since these files change frequently, I would like to get their modification date automatically.

Comment: The feature you describe is not built into Jekyll, for either posts or pages. I suppose in theory you could write a [Jekyll plugin](https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll/wiki/Plugins) which utilizes Ruby's `File.mtime`, but that seems like more trouble than it's worth. Plus, there could be some unintended consequences. What if, for instance, you want to edit a page's frontmatter without updating its modification date? I think a custom variable is the best way to go.

Answer (score 4):

If you're using Git, you can install a pre-commit hook that automatically updates the date field in the front matter of modified files. I was very surprised to learn that a pre-commit hook can indeed change the contents of the commit! You only have to manually install a pre-commit hook into each clone of the repository -- the following rough draft works for me for updating the overall modification time of the entire website:

```
#!/bin/sh
# Contents of .git/hooks/pre-commit

set -e
set -x

sed -i "s/^date:.*$/date: $(TZ=UTC date "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z")/" _config.yml
git add _config.yml
```

The `_config.yml` is expected to have a field "date", its contents will be replaced by each commit. It can be then accessed via `{{ site.date }}`. Example:

```
date: 2015-04-10 10:51:37 UTC
```

The script can be generalized to update only those pages or posts that have changed (query via `git diff-index --cached`) -- I don't have the time to implement this but I'd be interested to learn if a neater solution pops out eventually.