# Jekyll auto-generated titles from file names

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jekyll, github-pages

I would like to write files like:

- `ideas.md`
- `social-pomodoro.md`
- `ynm.md`

And not have to write titles, eg:

```
---
title: Ideas
---
```

But titles should be generated from filenames using something similar to Rails [`#humanize`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html#method-i-humanize) method.

Answer (score 3):

As this isn't a built-in functionality of Jekyll (at time of writing), I suppose you have 2 options:

1. Write a your post, and then use the `{{ post.path }}` tag and manipulate the path to get the filename and save that as the post title.

This would however require you to write frontmatter and other post details. [Here's a related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13243469/how-can-a-jekyll-page-access-its-filename).

2. **(recommended)** Use a script to generate the filename based on the title.

This is similar but a reverse of what you wanted, in which a script would take in parameters such as post title and post tags, and generate a file with the correct Jekyll post filename (name-of-post-2015-01-30) (I think Jekyll posts need dates to avoid collisions). The script will also generate the appropriate YAML front matter so you can get writing right away and not deal with repetitive overhead. **All you would have to do it something like** `./post.sh "Title" "optional_tags` and you're good to go!

[Here is a Python script](https://github.com/jbranchaud/mybin/blob/master/jekyll-post) [written by Josh Branchadu](http://joshbranchaud.com/blog/2013/01/11/Jekyll-Post.html) that creates the file with details like dates and filenames all taken care of. There's also a [similar bash version](http://themainthread.com/blog/2014/11/jekyll-new-post-script.html) as well. Lastly a [a script that uses the Thor Ruby in automating Jekyll posts](http://www.guyroutledge.co.uk/blog/automate-jekyll-post-creation-with-thor/) that should let you create a post in the most painless way possible.